# How to Display appropriate localisation based

Tags: magento-1.9

I'd like to configure the Magento site to be able to recognize the default language and location of the user and display the site in that language and with appropriate localisation.

For example:

A user from India with Indian language as default will go directly to the Indian Language website with Rubles as the default currency and prices.

Is this possible? If so how?

Answer (score 2):

possible of duplicate the same issue posted here and you can get answer [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/4/displaying-appropriate-localisation-based-on-location)

Comment: It may be a bit different, if you want to read out the request header Accept-Language. But yes, a good candidate for duplicate.